# 'Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function'

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button that removes banner on click. I wanted to add a dialog which will ask for confirmation if user has accidentally clicked on the button. I added this code(I've used it so many times and every time it worked):

```
$('.rem_cover_btn').click(function(){
    confirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove your banner?");
    if(confirm){
        window.location='../modules/user/removeBanner.php';
    }
});
```

And when I click on the button, the dialog box comes up and if I click 'Cancel' and repeat that action, dialog box won't show, I just get this message in Chrome Development Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function'

So: **'Remove Banner' button click > Cancel action > Again click on the button > Error is displayed**

I don't know why does it work for the first time and every time after that I get that error.

Comment: Use `var` and don't name your variables the same as existing functions or you will have a bad time.

Comment: Don't be a [Cargo cult programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: @asawyer Sorry, but I'm not a Cargo cult programmer. I didn't just paste the code. I'm 16 and making an advanced website(for me) isn't so easy and not finding a little bug doesn't make me the Cc programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code is *overwriting* the native `confirm` function

```
confirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove your banner?");
```

It overwrites it with the result of `confirm` which is a boolean value. The next time this code executes, `confirm` is a boolean value and when `()` is used on it an error is produced because it expected there to be a function present.

Consider avoiding using variable names which correlate to actual native api names. Perhaps `removeBanner` as it is a more descriptive name. Moreover, without prefixing the variable name with `var` it will use the global scope. This is also a glaring issue, and using `var` will save major headaches in the future.

```
$('.rem_cover_btn').click(function(){
 var removeBanner = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove your banner?");
 if(removeBanner){
  window.location='../modules/user/removeBanner.php';
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks and btw, that "short circuit" approach doesn't work so well:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (that line when the confirm starts) but you explained everything perfect.

Comment: @Vlada903 - Ah, right, the right hand side would need to be a function call. I used a simple css call when testing. Probably overkill to wrap the location call in a function in order to make that work. I am going to edit it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change code to this:

`$('.rem_cover_btn').click(function(){
    var confirmResult;
    confirmResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove your banner?");
    if(confirmResult){
        window.location='../modules/user/removeBanner.php';
    }
});`

**Explanation:**
You accidentally "rewrite" `confirm` function. Variable declaration without `var` makes variable in global scope(or rewrite something).
In your case:

- you call `confirm` function and rewrite the variable which "holds" this function
- you try to call this function second time, but now variable `confirm` contains a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

you must declare a var:

```
$('.rem_cover_btn').click(function(){
    var confirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove your banner?");
    if(confirm){
        window.location='../modules/user/removeBanner.php';
    }
});
```